How to get rid of floating keyboard on Android emulator?
I'm working with Android emulator, the keyboard was a fine, docked keyboard. Today out of nowhere, it started floating:

I can't find any way to "dock" it back to bottom. I tried dragging it to the bottom, while it does get dragged, it won't dock. I've also seen a YouTube video saying that there should be a "floating" option when I tap the options button (the initial button in the top of the keyboard), however in my case I don't have it:

I tried Resize and it also won't work. I went to settings and couldn't find anything about floating/docking of the keyboard.
This is preventing me from testing layout of the app that I'm working on with keyboard open.
How can I get back a docked, standard soft keyboard on an Android emulator (API level 35)?

Same way you would on any Android device.  Its an option on the keyboard app itself.  Or worst case, create a new emulator-  takes about 30 seconds and a new emulator has factory settings.

@GabeSechan where is the option? I've never used an Android device in my daily life and I'm not really familiar with the options. Also, I need to test something with the current installation of my app on this device in particular that's why I didn't create a new emulator. It would be great if you show exactly where I could toggle the option as I can't find a 'keyboard app' anywhere, nor I've installed something explicitly.

In Android the keboard is an app that can be swapped out.  There is no "Android keyboard" that's default across Android, every OEM has the right to install whatever it wish as a built in keyboard.  So if your layout doesn't work in this mode, I'd consider fixing it for this as well.  But on the default keyboard installed on the most recent AS emulator, the floating button should be on that last screen in your screenshot.  However you can drag and reoder those butons, so you must have deleted it somehow.  I'd try clearing storage on the keyboard app and seeing if that fixes it

FYI that particular keyboard is called "GBoard".  It should be in your phone apps list.

@GabeSechan thank you! I've tried to uninstall it, it didn't uninstall but used size has went down after I tapped "uninstall" in Google Play, so I assume it did something (perhaps it got updated/settings messed up, and after uninstall emulator automatically reinstalled it), also reset all settings. It worked and floating option is now there, though interestingly I can never get rid of it now even if I try to (not a problem, just trying to understand "how" I got rid of it in the first place), but anyway "uninstall"/reset all settings seemed to do the trick.

This floating keyboard is new feature on Gboard call "Write in text fields".

To get back the floating button:
Gboard > Settings > Write in text fields > Show on-screen keyboard, turn it on.
To disable the "Write in text fields" feature:
Gboard > Settings > Write in text fields > Use stylus to write in text fields, turn it off.


This was the only solution that worked.

What worked for me: I agree turn off "Write in text fields -> Use stylus to write in text fields".  But the other setting is wrong, it only applies when "Use stylus" is on.  Instead, there's another setting with the same "Show on-screen keyboard" that appears in the "Physical keyboard" group, and that's the one that should be turned on.

@BenVoigt Looks they just removed "Write in text fields" feature after some updates.

For some reason, after an hour of toggling settings here and there, reinstalling and trying everything again, going to the keyboard settings from within the keyboard itself and then toggling on-screen keyboard helped.
Strangely, now I do have the floating/non-floating setting in the keyboard and I can dock/undock with no issues.
I have no idea how it got messed up though I think a combination of "reset app settings", "uninstall Gboard" (it doesn't uninstall though the disk usage went down significantly so something has changed) and "toggle software keyboard" should have done the trick.

For me, clearing the app data for GBoard did the trick
